# Retrieve PHP Variable via jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know this questions has been asked in various forms, but I've been unable to find a response that squares with what I'm trying to accomplish.  Total amateur, so any additional pointers are appreciated.

**The Task:**
Use a form on page1 to post data to PHP file, which then searches the MySQL table for rows corresponding to the `$_POST[]`. Then, the PHP file echoes the result as `JSON_encode($variable)`. From there, the PHP file redirects the user back to page1, which (in theory) has a JQuery script that calls the `$variable` from the PHP file and create html with the data.

The Code:
PHP

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
session_save_path('path');
mysql_connect("", "", "")or die(); mysql_select_db("db")or die();
$pname = $_POST['country'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM project WHERE name = '$pname'");      
$array = mysql_fetch_row($result);  
echo json_encode($array);
header("page1.html");
?>
```

html/jquery/ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'page.php',
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#content1').html(data);
        },
    });
});
// ]]></script>
<div id="content1"></div>
```

The php script works and echoes the JSON encoded variable, but nothing on #content1...
I have a feeling either my code is wrong, or the data is lost while posting to the PHP file and then redirecting.

Comment: What is `header("page1.html")` supposed to do? Did you mean `header("Location: page1.html")`? If you do that, you can't use `echo`.

Comment: The argument to `html()` should be a string of HTML code. The JSON will decode into a Javascript object, not HTML.

Comment: Oops.  Header is correct on the php file, I was removing the actual file name and deleted the whole thing.

Comment: Still, it doesn't make sense to put a redirect in a script used via AJAX. And PHP generates an error if you try to use `header()` after `echo`.

Comment: OK, let me try again without using 'header()'...  Would it make more sense to post from JQuery ajax?

Comment: More sense than what? That's what you're doing. However, you're not passing any parameters, and the script expects a `country` parameter. You're also not waiting for the user to fill in the form, you're calling `$.ajax` as soon as the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to append the variable `data` to the content but the variable is called `result`. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready( function() {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: 'page.php',
data: '',
dataType: 'json',
cache: false,
success: function(result) {
$('#content1').html(result);//<- this used to be $('#content1').html(data);
},
});
});
// ]]></script>
<div id="content1"></div>
```

Additionally, as many have pointed out you are simply outputting the json at the moment - there is nothing in place to generate the table.

Comment: plus. PHP is sending over an json'd array, so OP is trying to stuff a javascript array into an html context. square hole, round peg...

Comment: OK, made that change, but still no data.  Is there a better way to do this?  I'm sort of compiling a "Frakenstein" code at this point...

Comment: Alert or log the "result" variable in the success area. Check to see what exactly is in there.

Answer (score 0):

Change $('#content1').html(data) to $('#content1').html(result);